# Can't read .txt file with pandas because it's in a weird shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that contains information from an experiment about particles. You can find it here (hope links are ok, if not let me know and i'll remove immediately) :

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/MiniBooNE+particle+identification

Trying to read this set in pandas and im encountering the problem of pandas reading this txt as a data frame with 130.064 lines, which is correct, but 1 column. If you check the txt file in the link, you will see that it is in a weird shape, with spaces in the beginning and then 2 spaces between each column. 
I tried the command

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/file.txt", header = None)
```

and also

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/file.txt", sep = "  ", header = None)
```

where I set 2 spaces as the separator. Nothing works. The file also, in the 1st line, has 2 numbers that just represent the number of rows, which I deleted. For someone who can't/doesn't want to open the link or the data set, here is a picture of some columns.

[image]

This is just a portion of it and not the whole data. In the leftmost side, there are 2 spaces between the edge of the window and the first column, as I said. When reading it using pandas this is what I get

[image]

Any advice/help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

**EDIT**
I tried doing the following and I think it worked. First I imported the .txt file using NumPy, after deleting the first row from the data frame which contains the two irrelevant numbers.

```
df1 = np.loadtxt("path/file.txt")
```

This, for some reason, worked and the resulting array was correct. Then I converted this array to data frame using the command

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df.columns = ['X' + str(x) for x in range(50) ]
```

And yeah, I think it works. Check the following picture.
[image]

I think its correct but if you guys find something wrong let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Edited

```
columns = ['Obs1','Obs2','Obs3','Obs4','Obs5','Obs6','Obs7','Obs8','Obs9','Obs10','Obs11','Obs12','Obs13','Obs14','Obs15','Obs16','Obs17','Obs18','Obs19','Obs20','Obs21','Obs22','Obs23','Obs24','Obs25','Obs26','Obs27','Obs28','Obs29','Obs30','Obs31','Obs32','Obs33','Obs34','Obs35','Obs36','Obs37','Obs38','Obs39','Obs40','Obs41','Obs42','Obs43','Obs44','Obs45','Obs46','Obs47','Obs48','Obs49','Obs50']    
df = pd.read_csv("path/file.txt", sep = "  ", columns=columns , skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work sadly, it gives the same results with my tries. :( Thanks a lot though

Comment: There is some pretty critical pieces of this that you left out.  Here is the break down of the data: EVENT 1 has 50 Columns of Observation.  So Each "row" is an event and should be 50 columns.

Comment: Yeah of course. Every row is an observation, a vector if you will, with 50 components. So 50 columns. How does that change the situation though?

Comment: this is really specific to your file for this usecase now.

Comment: This works better but the separators are weird in the txt, sometimes 1 space sometimes 2 spaces. As a result some values are nan. I think I figured something else out, if you wanna check my edit. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating the dataframe from lists instead of the txt file, something like the following:

```
#We put all the lines in a list
data = []
with open("dataset.txt") as fp:
    lines = fp.read()
    data = lines.split('\n')

df_data= []
for item in data:
    df_data.append(item.split('  ')) #I cant see if 1 space or 2 separate the values

#df_data should be something like [[row1col1,row1col2,row1col3],[row2col1,row2col2,row3col3]]

#List to dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

Doing this by memory so watch out for syntax, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This does create a data frame but many values are wrong, for example in one cell, say [i,j], there are more than 1 observations. Also many cells are left with "None". I'll try tweaking this a bit

Comment: Could it be that some separators are only 1 space or something like that? Maybe using another type of separator fixes the issue

Comment: This is true, some numbers are 1 space further from others, because some of them have a minus sign in front. Hmm.. Also, on the entire data set the last 4 columns are left with None on every entry.

Comment: One fast solution but not at all efficient would be to separate with 1 space and then erase blank spaces from all elements of the lists.

Comment: You could use `lstrip()` for doing this

Comment: Yeah I see. I might try that but I dont know. Im very inexperienced when it comes to the handling of situations like  this. But I'll see what I can do. Thanks